# How to get Href Text from PHP loop in Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am displaying anchor tag in php loop. Now I am trying to get text of these anchor tags which is coming from PHP loop in Jquery but I am getting the wrong Result. Check the Screen Shots Below...

[Anchor Tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSxnD.png)

[Wrong Result That I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upr8D.png)

Now when I click on any link Like **Baby Food** Or **Baby Furniture** Or any other link then I am getting the text of all Anchor Tags instead of specific anchor tag which is clicked. For Example when I click on **Baby Food** then I want Just **Baby Food** to be displayed not all Anchor Tag Text. Please Help me. Below is my code

**PHP**

```
<h4>Related Category</h4>

<?php foreach($grouped_with_count as $relatedCat) { ?>

<b> <?php echo $relatedCat['industry']; ?> </b>

<li> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="GetHref" onclick="RelatedCatLink(); return false;"><?php echo $relatedCat['product_type']; ?> </a> (<?php echo $relatedCat['count'];?>) </li>
<br />
<?php } ?>
```

**Jquery**

```
function RelatedCatLink(){

var href = $('.GetHref').text(); 
console.log(href);

//alert($('.GetHref').attr('href'));

   }
```

Please help me out. Thanks in advance..

Comment: `$('.GetHref')` selector gets *EVERY* element with class `GetHref`. You could change it to `var href = $(this).text();`.

Comment: Thanks. Its is working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem in your code**

You are using `class` for selection. There will be multiple `<a>` with the same class.

**Solution**

Pass the element along with your function call

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="GetHref" onclick="RelatedCatLink(this); return false;"><?php echo $relatedCat['product_type']; ?> </a> (<?php echo $relatedCat['count'];?>) </li>
```

**JS**

```
function RelatedCatLink(elem){
   var href = $(elem).text(); 
}
```

**Working Demo**

```js
function RelatedCatLink(elem){
   var href = $(elem).text(); 
   alert(href);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="GetHref" onclick="RelatedCatLink(this); return false;">1</a> </li>
<li> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="GetHref" onclick="RelatedCatLink(this); return false;">2</a> </li>
<li> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="GetHref" onclick="RelatedCatLink(this); return false;">3</a> </li>
<li> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="GetHref" onclick="RelatedCatLink(this); return false;">4</a> </li>
```

Comment: @Junaidafzal Always glad to here that `:)`

Answer (score 1):

```
//PHP CODE  

      <h4>Related Category</h4>

        <?php foreach($grouped_with_count as $relatedCat) { ?>

        <b> <?php echo $relatedCat['industry']; ?> </b>

        <li> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="GetHref" onclick="RelatedCatLink(<?php echo $relatedCat['id']; ?>); return false;" id="GetHref-<?php echo $relatedCat['id']; ?>"><?php echo $relatedCat['product_type']; ?> </a> (<?php echo $relatedCat['count'];?>) </li>
        <br />
        <?php } ?>



//JQUERY CODE    

    function RelatedCatLink(id){

    var href = $('#GetHref-'+id).text(); 
    console.log(href);

       }
```